# Handling PG connections for bulk update in loop

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using **psycopg2** module for performing update task of thousands of row. This update is based on condition, if X condition fails then only there will be an update operation.

So for this activity wanted to know what is recommended way to handle connection :

1. We use same connection for whole activity and then close connection in the end.
2. For every iteration create a connection and close it.

Also, incase a single update fails shall I just rollback or even close the connection.

Comment: Creating a connection is expensive and not necessary in your case. Reuse the same connection.

Comment: The recommended way is to use `INSERT` with [ON CONFLICT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) clause in a single connection.  As to failures use `try/except` to capture the error  log it, discard it, etc and move on to next statement.

Comment: Thanks Stefanov & Adrian